# Chrome Extension v3 with react - Add html to website via content script with react component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I try to implement a chrome extension (manifest v3) with react and webpack.
I want to simply add a "Hello World" to a website for testing, but the content script does not run. Even the console.log does not show up.

When I delete the complete code from the content.js and only add a console.log, this log shows up. So the manifest should be correct.

test.jsx

```
import React from "react";
function Test() {
   return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
export default Test;
```

index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import Test from "./test";

function init() {
    console.log("I am from react test content script.");

    const appContainer = document.createElement("div");
    appContainer.id = "react-root";
    document.body.insertBefore(appContainer, document.body.firstChild);

    if (!appContainer) {
        throw new Error("Cannot find appContainer");
    }

    const root = createRoot(appContainer);
    console.log(appContainer);
    root.render(<Test />);
}

init();
```

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.google.com/"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
```

EDIT: Files index.jsx and test.jsx are in folder "content".
webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
    popup: path.resolve("./src/popup/index.jsx"),
    content: path.resolve("./src/content/index.jsx"),
    options: path.resolve("./src/options/index.jsx"),
    background: path.resolve("./src/background/background.jsx"),
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"],
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "",
    filename: "[name].js",
    clean: true,
},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                ident: "postcss",
                                plugins: [tailwindcss, autoprefixer],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks(chunk) {
                // exclude `chunk`
                return chunk.name !== "content";
            },
        },
    },
```

content.js

```
(()=>{"use strict";var e,r={892:(e,r,t)=>{var o=t(294),n=t(745);const a=function(){return o.createElement("div",null,"Hello World")};!function(){console.log("I am from react test content script.");var e=document.createElement("div");if(e.id="react-root",document.body.insertBefore(e,document.body.firstChild),!e)throw new Error("Cannot find appContainer");var r=(0,n.s)(e);console.log(e),r.render(o.createElement(a,null))}()}},t={};function o(e){var n=t[e];if(void 0!==n)return n.exports;var a=t[e]={exports:{}};return r[e](a,a.exports,o),a.exports}o.m=r,e=[],o.O=(r,t,n,a)=>{if(!t){var l=1/0;for(f=0;f<e.length;f++){for(var[t,n,a]=e[f],i=!0,c=0;c<t.length;c++)(!1&a||l>=a)&&Object.keys(o.O).every((e=>o.O[e](t[c])))?t.splice(c--,1):(i=!1,a<l&&(l=a));if(i){e.splice(f--,1);var s=n();void 0!==s&&(r=s)}}return r}a=a||0;for(var f=e.length;f>0&&e[f-1][2]>a;f--)e[f]=e[f-1];e[f]=[t,n,a]},o.o=(e,r)=>Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r),(()=>{var e={904:0};o.O.j=r=>0===e[r];var r=(r,t)=>{var n,a,[l,i,c]=t,s=0;if(l.some((r=>0!==e[r]))){for(n in i)o.o(i,n)&&(o.m[n]=i[n]);if(c)var f=c(o)}for(r&&r(t);s<l.length;s++)a=l[s],o.o(e,a)&&e[a]&&e[a][0](),e[a]=0;return o.O(f)},t=self.webpackChunkreact_test=self.webpackChunkreact_test||[];t.forEach(r.bind(null,0)),t.push=r.bind(null,t.push.bind(t))})();var n=o.O(void 0,[745],(()=>o(892)));n=o.O(n)})();
```

Comment: Show your content.js and how it is compiled/declared in webpack.

Comment: @wOxxOm i added the code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The content.js needs its own DOM, because it has mo own .html file, so the file must be exluded from the webpack to get included. So in the webpack config part "optimization" instead of chunks: "all" there must be a condition which excludes the content chunk return chunk.name !== "content";.